# Coverting a data frame to matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I would like to convert a data frame to a matrix in R, as in the following example:

```html
df
row.index   column.index   matrix element
1           1              A
1           2              B
2           1              C
2           2              D

matrix
A  B
C  D
```

Is it possible to do the same with rownames? In example

```html
df
row.name   column.name   matrix element
X          P             A
X          Q             B
Y          P             C
Y          Q             D

matrix
     P  Q

X    A  B
Y    C  D
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: For case 1 `matrix(df$matrixelement, nrow = max(df$row.index), byrow = TRUE)` seems to do the trick. For case 2 `length(unique(df1$row.name))` in `nrow` will do it. You can then set `colnames` and `rownames`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `tapply`

```
tapply(df$matrixelement, df[1:2], FUN = I)
```

It would also work for the second dataset

```
res <- tapply(df1$matrixelement, df1[1:2], FUN = I)
names(dimnames(res)) <- NULL
res
#   P   Q  
#X "A" "B"
#Y "C" "D"
```

---

If we need a `data.frame`, then `dcast` can be used

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, row.index ~column.index)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(row.index = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), column.index = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), matrixelement = c("A", "B", "C", "D")), .Names = c("row.index", 
"column.index", "matrixelement"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df1 <- structure(list(row.name = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y"), column.name = c("P", 
"Q", "P", "Q"), matrixelement = c("A", "B", "C", "D")), .Names = c("row.name", 
"column.name", "matrixelement"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: I am getting an error on tapply: Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?

Comment: @mac I assumed you have a data.frame as input.  Please check the data in my post.  Convert your data, possibly matrix to data.fframe and then run it i.e. `df <- as.data.frame(df)` and try the code again

Comment: It was a data.table. I incorrectly assumed that a data.table always behaves like a data.frame

Comment: @mac For the data i showed, it is a `matrix` i.e. `is.matrix(res)
#[1] TRUE`  Here, we assume that there are length combinations are the same for the groups

Comment: OK, since it was a symmetric matrix I ignored permutations of indexes... maybe I should do something like df.new = rbind(df, df[ , c(2,1,3)]?

Comment: @mac If it is not symmetric, itis better to use `dcast` after creating a sequence column by the grouping variable